# HTML Parser (using SAX)

Tags: c++, html, parsing, c++14

Got bored writing a review on an HTML parser and decided I wanted to try.

So I threw this together to see I could parse an Amazon page.

```
curl -A 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080313 Firefox' https://www.amazon.com | parser
```

Look what I found on amazons home page:

```
Comment:        _
       .__(.)< (MEOW)
        \___)
 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Looks like a duck cat!!!

Note: This is not designed to parse valid HTML. The idea was to parse invalid HTML that is found on the web. So it makes allowances for a couple of common problems found in HTML that you see on the web.

It also assumes (incorrectly) that all text between `<script>` => `</script>` and `<style>` => `</style>` is one big blob of text.

#### parser.h

```
#ifndef THORSANVIL_HTMLPARSER_PARSER_H
#define THORSANVIL_HTMLPARSER_PARSER_H

#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <istream>

namespace ThorsAnvil
{
    namespace HTMLParser
    {

using Attributes = std::map<std::string, std::string>;

class HTMLTokenI
{
    public:
        virtual ~HTMLTokenI() {}
        // By default the functions deliberately do nothing.
        virtual void DocType(std::string const& docString) {}
        virtual void tagOpen(std::string const& tagName, Attributes const& attr) {}
        virtual void tagOpenClose(std::string const& tagName, Attributes const& attr) {}
        virtual void tagClose(std::string const& tagName) {}
        virtual void comment(std::string const& comment) {}
        virtual void text(std::string const& text) {}
        virtual void error(std::string const& message) {}
};

class HTMLSaxParser
{
    std::istream&   htmlpage;
    HTMLTokenI&     callback;
    public:
        HTMLSaxParser(std::istream& htmlpage, HTMLTokenI& callback)
            : htmlpage(htmlpage)
            , callback(callback)
        {}

        void parse();
    private:
        void parseDocType();
        void parseTag();
        void parseComment();
        void parseTagClose();
        void parseTagOpen();

        bool attributesFinished;
        Attributes readAttributes();
        bool       getAttribute(std::istream& s, std::string& attr);

        void getNonHtmlText(std::string const& tag);
};

    }
}

#endif
```

#### parser.cpp

```
#include "parser.h"

#include <cctype>
#include <vector>

using namespace ThorsAnvil::HTMLParser;

void HTMLSaxParser::parse()
{
    parseDocType();

    std::string text;
    while(std::getline(htmlpage, text, '<'))
    {
        if (!text.empty())
        {
            callback.text(text);
        }
        if (htmlpage.good())
        {
            parseTag();
        }
    }
}

void HTMLSaxParser::parseDocType()
{
    char firstChar;
    while(htmlpage.get(firstChar) && std::isspace(firstChar))
    {
        // ignore space
    }
    if (!htmlpage)
    {
        callback.error("Empty Page");
        return;
    }
    if (firstChar == '<')
    {
        char secondChar = htmlpage.get();
        if (!htmlpage)
        {
            callback.error("Bad page only contains '<'");
            return;
        }
        if (secondChar == '!')
        {
            std::string docType;
            std::getline(htmlpage, docType, '>');
            callback.DocType(docType);
        }
        else
        {
            htmlpage.unget();
            htmlpage.unget();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        htmlpage.unget();
    }
}

void HTMLSaxParser::parseTag()
{
    // Note this function is called after the␣
    // initial '<' has been removed from the stream.
    char nextChar;
    while (htmlpage.get(nextChar) && std::isspace(nextChar))
    {
        // common error is to place leading space inside a tag.
        // let us ignore it to be good citizens. This is not valid
        // in html but a lot of pages on the web have this issue.
        callback.error("Leading Space in Tag");
    }
    if (htmlpage)
    {
        if (nextChar == '!')
        {
            parseComment();
        }
        else if (nextChar == '/')
        {
            parseTagClose();
        }
        else
        {
            htmlpage.unget();
            parseTagOpen();
        }
    }
}

void HTMLSaxParser::parseComment()
{
    std::string  comment;
    char nextChar1 = '\0';
    char nextChar2 = '\0';
    if (htmlpage.get(nextChar1) && nextChar1 == '-' && htmlpage.get(nextChar2) && nextChar2 == '-')
    {
        std::string commentPart;
        while(std::getline(htmlpage, commentPart, '>'))
        {
            if (commentPart.size() >= 2 && commentPart[commentPart.size() - 2] == '-' && commentPart[commentPart.size() - 1] == '-')
            {
                comment += commentPart.substr(0, commentPart.size() - 2);
                break;
            }
            comment += commentPart;
            comment += '>';
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (nextChar1 != '-')
        {
            htmlpage.unget();
        }
        htmlpage.unget();
        std::getline(htmlpage, comment, '>');
        callback.error("Badly formed Comment");
    }
    callback.comment(comment);
}

void HTMLSaxParser::parseTagClose()
{
    std::string tag;
    std::getline(htmlpage, tag, '>');

    auto find = std::find_if(std::begin(tag), std::end(tag), [](char x){return std::isspace(x);});
    if (find != std::end(tag))
    {
        callback.error("Badly formed close");
        tag = tag.substr(0, std::distance(std::begin(tag), find));
    }
    callback.tagClose(tag);
}

void HTMLSaxParser::parseTagOpen()
{
    std::string tag;
    char        nextCharacter;
    while(htmlpage.get(nextCharacter) && nextCharacter != '>' && nextCharacter != '/' && !std::isspace(nextCharacter))
    {
        tag += std::tolower(nextCharacter);
    }

    Attributes  attributes;
    bool        openClose = false;

    if (nextCharacter != '>' && nextCharacter != '/')
    {
        attributes = readAttributes();
    }

    if (nextCharacter == '>')
    {
        // Normal Valid Tag
    }
    else if (nextCharacter == '/')
    {
        // HTML5 or XHTML Open/Close tag
        openClose = true;
        if (!htmlpage.get(nextCharacter))
        {
            callback.error(std::string("Badly Formed Tag. Close File in tag: ") + tag);
        }
        else if (nextCharacter != '>')
        {
            callback.error(std::string("Badly Formed Tag. Expected '>' after '/' got: ") + nextCharacter + " in: " + tag);
            std::string ignore;
            std::getline(htmlpage, ignore, '>');
        }
    }

    static std::vector<std::string> selfClosingTags = {"area", "base", "br", "col", "embed", "hr", "img", "input", "keygen", "link", "meta", "param", "source", "track", "wbr"};

    openClose = openClose || std::find(std::begin(selfClosingTags), std::end(selfClosingTags), tag) != std::end(selfClosingTags);
    if (openClose)
    {
        callback.tagOpenClose(tag, attributes);
    }
    else
    {
        callback.tagOpen(tag, attributes);
        if (tag == "script" || tag == "style")
        {
            // The content inside these tags is not HTML
            // So search for the closing tag now rather
            // than use the generic routines.
            getNonHtmlText(tag);
        }
    }
}

void HTMLSaxParser::getNonHtmlText(std::string const& tag)
{
    std::string program;
    std::string part;
    while(std::getline(htmlpage, part, '<'))
    {
        char nextChar;

        if (htmlpage.get(nextChar) && nextChar == '/')
        {
            bool fail = false;
            int  loop;
            for(loop = 0; loop < tag.size(); ++loop)
            {
                if (!htmlpage.get(nextChar) || nextChar != tag[loop])
                {
                    fail = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            for(;loop >= 0; --loop)
            {
                htmlpage.unget();
            }
            if (!fail)
            {
                htmlpage.unget();
                htmlpage.unget();
                break;
            }
        }

        program += part;
        program += '<';
        program += nextChar;
    }
    program += part;
    callback.text(program);
}

bool HTMLSaxParser::getAttribute(std::istream& s, std::string& attr)
{
    attr.clear();
    if (attributesFinished)
    {
        return false;
    }

    bool result  = false;
    char nextChar;
    while(s.get(nextChar) && std::isspace(nextChar))
    {
        // ignore space
    }
    s.unget();

    while(s.get(nextChar) && nextChar != '>' && nextChar != '/' && !std::isspace(nextChar))
    {
        result = true;
        attr += nextChar;
        if (nextChar == '"' || nextChar == '\'')
        {
            char quote = nextChar;
            while(s.get(nextChar) && nextChar != quote)
            {
                attr += nextChar;
            }
            attr += nextChar;
        }
    }
    if (nextChar == '>' || nextChar == '/')
    {
        attributesFinished = true;
        s.unget();
    }
    return result;
}

Attributes HTMLSaxParser::readAttributes()
{
    Attributes  result;
    attributesFinished  = false;

    std::string     attribute;
    while(getAttribute(htmlpage, attribute))
    {
        std::string key;
        std::string value;

        auto equalSign  = attribute.find('=');
        if (equalSign == std::string::npos)
        {
            callback.error(std::string("Badly Defined Attribute: ") + attribute);
            key = attribute;
        }
        else
        {
            key   = attribute.substr(0, equalSign);
            value = attribute.substr(equalSign + 1);

            if (value[0] == '"' || value[0] == '\'')
            {
                if (value[value.size() - 1] == value[0])
                {
                    value = value.substr(1, value.size() - 2);
                }
                else
                {
                    callback.error(std::string("Badly quotes Attribute Value: Key=") + key + " value=" + value );
                }
            }
        }
        std::transform(std::begin(key), std::end(key), std::begin(key), [](char x){return std::tolower(x);});
        result[key] = value;
    }
    return result;
}
```

#### main.cpp

```
#include "parser.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

namespace tap = ThorsAnvil::HTMLParser;

class SimpleParser: public tap::HTMLTokenI
{
        void printLinkTags(std::string const& tagName, tap::Attributes const& attr)
        {
            tap::Attributes::const_iterator  find;
            if (tagName == "a" && (find = attr.find("href")) != attr.end())
            {
                std::cout << "A: Link: " << find->second << "\n";
            }
        }
    public:
        void tagOpen(std::string const& tagName, tap::Attributes const& attr) override
        {
            printLinkTags(tagName, attr);
        }
        void tagOpenClose(std::string const& tagName, tap::Attributes const& attr) override
        {
            printLinkTags(tagName, attr);
        }
        void error(std::string const& message) override
        {
            std::cout << "Error: " << message << "\n";
        }
        void comment(std::string const& comment) override
        {
            std::cout << "Comment: " << comment << "\n";
        }
};

int main()
{
    std::ifstream       amazon("t1");
    SimpleParser        parser;
    tap::HTMLSaxParser  sax(amazon, parser);

    sax.parse();
}
```

Comment: What standard are you using, 03, 11, 14?

Comment: @pacmaninbw: The current one: C++14

Comment: [The link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6828703/what-is-the-difference-between-sax-and-dom) will be useful to everyone who doesn't have any idea what is SAX parser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Minor nitpicks, I suppose.

1. You need to add

   ```
   #include <algorithm>
   ```

   to use `std::find` and `std::find_if`.
2. Make `loop` an `unsigned` type.

   You have

   ```
   int loop;
   for(loop = 0; loop < tag.size(); ++loop)
   ```

   That produces a compiler warning from g++:

   warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]

   I suggest changing that to:

   ```
   decltype(tag.size()) loop;
   for(loop = 0; loop < tag.size(); ++loop)
   ```
3. Example usage and real usage don't match.

   Your example usage says:

   ```
   curl -A '.....' www.amazon.com | parser
   ```

   However, in `main` you are using a hard coded filename, named "t1".

   ```
   std::ifstream       amazon("t1");
   ```

   The usage should be:

   ```
   curl -A '.....' www.amazon.com > t1 && ./parser
   ```